# Plotly JS Parallel Coordinates - Change Axis Color

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am using Plotly for creating a [parallel coordinate](https://plotly.com/javascript/parallel-coordinates-plot/) plot and am trying to customize the axis colors. I have a webpage with a dark background and have set the plot background to a dark color as well. However, for the parallel coordinate plot, the lines for the axes remain black and are therefore nearly invisible.

I am able to change axis line colors on other plot types (such as "bar" and "box" plots) by specifying the `linecolor`, `linewidth`, and `tickcolor` in the `xaxis` and `yaxis` objects in the plot's `layout`. However, this does not seem to modify the axis line colors for a "parcoords" plot.

I am also able to successfully change the parallel coordinate axis labels by specifying `labelfont`, `rangefont`, and `tickfont` in the `data` object, but could not find anything else there for specifying the axis line colors.